# Is possible use Server-sent Events front de back-end and listen it from other back-end without use a front-end browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, events, server-sent-events

I have a question about Server-sent Events, I would like to implement in a spring boot application but the question I want to listen to these events from the other spring boot application or back-end this is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use a webclient that does support SSE. [Jersey](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/sse.html#sse-client-jaxrs) and [SpringBoot](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/html/web-reactive.html#web-reactive-client) have a such client as many other libraries.

You can find a short code example that plugs to a SSE server here: https://github.com/streamdataio/streamdataio-spring-webflux

It's related to this blog post: https://streamdata.io/blog/using-spring-web-flux-as-a-java-client-of-streamdata-io/

This should give you an insight about how to do it using Spring WebFlux.